# Sattelite Assembly - pros and cons

Tags: c#, .net, satellite-assembly

I am planning to store non executable files of my solution in satellite assembly. Reason is which can be shared easily and only the application can see and use it. But I am not sure about it's short comings. Need feedback from those who has prior experience using satellite assembly. 
FYI... i will be storing images, text and MS Access file.

Comment: Are you going to alter your MS Access file in some way or it would be there only for read purpose?

Comment: No there is no need to alter the MS Access file; MSAccess file used to store global parameters for refering it in application. Now in case there is any change in the parameters new assembly will be generated and distributed. That satellite assembly will have exclusive rights...

Answer (score 1):

From my experience it's more convenient to put images to separate folder and configuration to the `.config`. Moving images into the satellite assembly could be useful if you want to protect or hide your raw images from the users. Nevertheless if you're ready to update your satellite assembly on demand then I guess there is nothing prevents you from using it.

Comment: So you are saying that I am good in using it but there has to be some limitations to it in long run which I am unable to anticipate at this initial moment. See, I donot want to get to a situation that I have to take another approach after deploying the application.